# Getting whole line from files

Tags: c++, string, structure, ifstream, getline

My program Can read strings and integer, but the problem is when I add spaces for strings like names it does not execute the viewOrder() function. I am New to programming and start learning c++ as my frist language at 19 years old, hoping that someone can help me. I am doing an uniform ordering system.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
struct orderDetails{
    string name;
    int studentNumber;
    string address;
    string dressCode;
    int quantity; 
};

void takeOrder(){
    orderDetails order;
        ofstream file ("database.dat" , ios::app);
        cin.ignore();

        cout << "Enter name: ";
        getline(cin,order.name);

        cout << "Enter Student Number: ";
        cin >> order.studentNumber;
        cin.ignore();

        cout << "Enter Address: ";
        getline(cin,order.address);
        
        
        cout << "Enter Dress Code: ";
        cin >> order.dressCode;

        cout << "Enter Quantity: ";
        cin >> order.quantity;

         file << order.name << endl 
                << order.studentNumber << endl 
                << order.address << endl 
                << order.dressCode << endl 
                << order.quantity << endl;

        file.close();
}

void viewOrder(){
    ifstream database("database.dat");
    orderDetails order;

    while(database >> order.name >> order.studentNumber >> order.address >> order.dressCode >> order.quantity){
        cout  << endl << order.name << endl << order.studentNumber << endl << order.address << endl << order.dressCode << endl << order.quantity << endl;
    }
    
}

int main(){
    cout << "1.Take Order \n2.View Order \n3.Exit \nPlease Choose A Number: ";
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
        system("CLS");
        takeOrder();
        break;

        case 2:
        system("CLS");
        viewOrder();
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice that you use `getline` to read strings for `name` and `address` but `operator>>` for `dressCode`. The fact that those two operations have slightly different behavior dealing with whitespace and newlines often leads to subtle misbehaviors in code, including in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old problem. You need to learn about the difference between formatted and unformatted input.

If you have a line of text like

```
abc def
```

and you read this into `std::string`s with

```
inputFileStream >> s1 >> s2
```

Then the input "abc" and "def" will be read into the to string-variables. Ok. But, the newline ('\n') at the end of the line will not be consumed. If you write an additional

```
inputFileStream >> s1 >> s2
```

to read the next line, then the inserter operator >> will skip the whitespace '\n' and read the strings as you would expect.

But, if you use `std::getline` after the initial formatted input, then, and remember that there is still a not-consumed '\n' at the end of the line, only an empty string and the newline will be read.

To overcome this situation, you can use `std::ws`. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) for a description. So, you simply add this in your `std::getline` statement.

Like this:

```
std::getline(ifs >> std::ws, line);
```

This will eat up all white spaces (including '\n') in front of the next text that you want to read.

To explain it better. This is a nested statement. So, first `ifs >> std::ws` is executed. This operation returns again `ifs` and then the `std::getline` will be done. You can of course also use `ifs >> std::ws` outside of the `std::getline`. That is in most cases better than calling `ignore`.

But remember. This is only necessary, if you switch from formatted to unformatted input.

Comment: Hi sir! It worked, I really want to thank you for such help. I've been solving this problem for a day and thanks for helping out. I am new to programming and this is my first language (c++) and I am not too fluent or master  yet this language. So thanks again